# How to mod-rewrite this URL in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following url structure:

```
http://localhost/sitename/views/www/page.php
```

I would like for page.php to show up even if the user enters:

```
http://localhost/page
```

How to do this using htaccess? Please keep in mind that a lot of different pages will be in the same directory level as page.php and I would like for all of them to be accessible the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /sitename/views/www/$1.php [L]
```

This will display the expected page with no redirect. Replace `[L]` with `[R=permanent,L]` if you wish the browser to be redirected.